# Error while compiling srilm in linux ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, linux, machine-translation, moses

I am trying to install SRILM on my computer using os linux ubuntu 12.04, the gcc version 4.6.3 and the machine type is i686. at the end of the process it gives result of 2 errors as follows:

-o ../obj/i686/tclmain.o tclmain.cc
tclmain.cc:8:17: fatal error: tcl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [../obj/i686/tclmain.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/supriadi/workspace/srilm/misc/src'
make[1]: *** [release-libraries] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/supriadi/workspace/srilm'
make: *** [World] Error 2

what should I do to fix this problem? thanks friend

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the dev files of tcl. Use

```
sudo apt-get install tcl-dev tk-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install tcl development files.

You can find tcl-dev package for ubuntu 12.04 here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/tcl-dev

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of make:

```
 make MACHINE_TYPE=i686-m64 World
```

or

```
 make NO_TCL=1 MACHINE_TYPE=i686-ubuntu World
```

In my case this lead me into another error

> /usr/include/features.h:323:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such
>   file or directory

Which I found a fix [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1877944), such that:

```
 sudo aptitude install libc6-dev-amd64
```

Comment: Also I this might be useful in the beginning: sudo aptitude install tcl tcl-dev csh gawk